# How to prevent Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 to add telemetry_main_invoke_trigger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

[A simple C++ console app](http://www.geeks3d.com/20160610/vs2015-how-to-remove-windows-telemetry-function-call-from-your-c-binaries/)

```
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

compiled in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 adds a call to `telemetry_main_invoke_trigger` to both Debug and Release binaries.

[image]

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Full thread [here on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/4ibauu/visual_studio_adding_telemetry_function_calls_to/)

Answer (score 10):

According to [Microsoft’s Steve Carroll](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/4ibauu/visual_studio_adding_telemetry_function_calls_to/d30dmvu) (Development Manager for the Visual C++ team), you can remove telemetry calls by adding `notelemetry.obj` to the command options of the linker:

[image]

Steve Carroll explained that this will be removed in the upcoming Update 3:

> Our intent was benign – our desire was to build a framework that will
>   help investigate performance problems and improve the quality of our
>   optimizer should we get any reports of slowdowns or endemic perf
>   problems in the field. We apologize for raising the suspicion levels
>   even further by not including the CRT source, this was just an
>   oversight on our part. Despite that, some of you already investigated
>   how this mechanism works in nice detail. As you have already called
>   out, what the code does is trigger an ETW event which, when it’s
>   turned on, will emit timestamps and module loads events. The event
>   data can only be interpreted if a customer gives us symbol information
>   (i.e. PDBs) so this data is only applicable to customers that are
>   actively seeking help from us and are willing to share these PDBs as
>   part of their investigation. We haven’t actually gone through this
>   full exercise with any customers to date though, and we are so far
>   relying on our established approaches to investigate and address
>   potential problems instead. We plan to remove these events in Update
>   3. In the meantime, to remove this dependency in Update 2, you should add notelemetry.obj to your linker command line.

Comment: Can i add this into source code with a #pragma comment lib line ?

Comment: It doesn't appear to work. I end up with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\notelemetry.obj : warning LNK4003: invalid library format; library ignored` and the telemetry stubs are still present in the binary.

Comment: this is the x86 one, if you compile for x64 the lib from amd64 must be used