# CMake set Visual Studio Linker ->Command Line-> Additional Options

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2015

What needs to be added to the CMakeLists.txt file of the project so that the `notelemetry.obj` option is appended to the Visual Studio 2019's `Linker ->Command Line-> Additional Options` field.

`notelemetry.obj` is **not a file**, it is **an option passed to the linker** so that it won't embed data collection logic in your code.

[See this if you are interested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761768/how-to-prevent-visual-studio-2015-update-2-to-add-telemetry-main-invoke-trigger), my question is how do you pass this option to the linker with cmake?

Comment: What meaning of this option would be? Do you want to link your executable/library with already created object file? Or what?

Comment: @Tsyvarev It is something I have carried over from earlier versions of VS, now would like to put it in cmake. It once was offered as a solution to prevent data collection code being put in the executable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761768/how-to-prevent-visual-studio-2015-update-2-to-add-telemetry-main-invoke-trigger

Comment: @Tsyvarev I just want that option to appear under the additional options field when I look in the Project Properties->Linker->CommandLine ->Additional Options

Comment: Oh, so it is just a special option for the linker. You may use [add_link_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_link_options.html) or [target_link_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html) for add it. See e.g. that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24532853/how-to-add-linker-flag-for-libraries-with-cmake

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks add_link_options worked. If you could provide your comment as an answer, I will gladly mark it so.

Comment: On Stack Overflow we tend to not duplicate answers for different questions. I have linked your question to the one which contains many answers with different approaches for adding linker flags in CMake.